# Draw route between points using Here iOS SDK in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, maps, here-api

All

I'm working with here maps for navigation app, so to enable navigation i need to draw route between points. I found rest api in "Here" developer console. i'm getting maneuver from the response, but i don't understand how to draw with those points.

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=17.4401,78.3489&waypoint1=17.3916,78.4401&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&app_id={App_id}&app_code={App_code}&departure=now&language=en-us
```

Thanks in Advance, please help me on it

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try google directions api, It provides array of route points in "routes" array.

This points are lat long combinations and can be easyliy plotted on Map to show route.

Link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: yes but to avoid some area between the points i need to go for Here maps, google maps doesn't support this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDK, then you don't need to use REST API. SDK do it for you.
Start to read from https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/routing-intro.html or look into example https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/tree/master/routing-ios